# Invariant Violantion expected string, getting object--from php page that echos a string

Tags: react-native

I'm extremely new to React Native.  I'm logging in a user.  Here's the [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/making-a-login-app-using-react-native-and-hasura-without-redux-bb31d102038d) I'm going off.  I had to use XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch because I couldn't get it to pass the POST parameters correctly.  The PHP page it posts to just echos out the userID before returning.  It's not returning a json string or anything.

I'm logging in the user and using

```
this.setState({ userID: request.responseText });
```

to keep track of the userID.  This line is giving me the Invariant Violation error, that it expects a string and I'm giving it an object.

App.js ( I included the commented out fetch in case you saw any obvious answers)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text,  Alert, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Home from './Home';
export default class App extends Component{
  state = {
    email: '',
    pwd: '',
    auth_token: '',
    userID: ''
  }

  Login = async () => {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var params = "email=" + this.state.email + "&pwd=" + this.state.pwd;
      request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('success', request.responseText);  
    Alert.alert(request.responseText); //this is returning the correct value
    if(request.responseText != "ERROR"){
       this.setState({ userID: request.responseText });
       Alert.alert("Welcome", " You have succesfully logged in");//also returning
    }else{
        Alert.alert("Oh, no!", " There was a problem");
    }
  } else {
    console.warn('error');
  }
};

request.open('POST', 'https://mysitexzy.com/wLoginCE');
request.send(params);
/*
    fetch('https://mysitexzy.com/wLoginCE', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
   // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
  //          "provider": "username",
            "email": this.state.email,
            "pwd": this.state.pwd

          })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
      if(typeof(res.message) != "undefined"){
       Alert.alert("Error", "Error: "+ res.message);
      }
      else{
        this.setState({ userID: response });
        Alert.alert("Welcome", " You have succesfully logged in");
        }
     }).catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
        });
        */
  }
  render(){
  //If auth token is not present
   if(this.state.userID==''){
     return(
     <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
      }}>
     <TextInput
           placeholder="Enter User name"
           onChangeText={ TextInputValue =>
           this.setState({email : TextInputValue }) }
           underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
           style={
           {
               textAlign: 'center',
               width: '90%',
               marginBottom: 7,
               height: 40,
               borderRadius: 5 ,
               fontSize: 20,
           }
         }
         />
     <TextInput
           placeholder="Enter password"
           onChangeText={ TextInputValue =>
           this.setState({pwd: TextInputValue }) }
           underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
           secureTextEntry={true}
           style={
           {
               textAlign: 'center',
               width: '90%',
               marginBottom: 7,
               height: 40,
               borderRadius: 5 ,
               fontSize: 20,
           }
         }
         />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.Login.bind(this)}>
        <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor:
        '#cc0066',justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',}}>
          <Text style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          }}> 
          Login </Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>
        );
      }
/* Checking if the auth token is not empty directly sending the user to Home screen */
      else{
        return(
          <Home />
        );
    }
}
}
```

Home.js is blank per the instructions in the tutorial.

Comment: Please post the code of the Home.js file too. It should export atleast a View as it's  default export.

Comment: @HishamMubarak Thanks for your response.  I've modified some of what I'm doing so it's different now and I don't have anything to send you.  But thank you for taking the time to look at my question!

Comment: Cool, I assume you got it working. And all the best for your react native learning path.